# applying non-zero offset 4 to null pointer

Tags: c++, sorting, runtime-error, greedy

There are some spherical balloons taped onto a flat wall that represents the XY-plane. The balloons are represented as a 2D integer array points where points[i] = [xstart, xend] denotes a balloon whose horizontal diameter stretches between xstart and xend. You do not know the exact y-coordinates of the balloons.

Arrows can be shot up directly vertically (in the positive y-direction) from different points along the x-axis. A balloon with xstart and xend is burst by an arrow shot at x if xstart <= x <= xend. There is no limit to the number of arrows that can be shot. A shot arrow keeps traveling up infinitely, bursting any balloons in its path.

Given the array points, return the minimum number of arrows that must be shot to burst all balloons

```
bool compare(vector<int> &a,vector<int> &b){
          return a[1]<=b[1];
}
class Solution {
public:
    int findMinArrowShots(vector<vector<int>>& points) {
        if(points.size()==1) return 1;
        sort(points.begin(),points.end(),compare);
        int arrows=1,end=points[0][1];
        for(int i=1;i<points.size();i++){
            if(points[i][0]>end){
                arrows++;
                end=points[i][1];
            }
        }
        return arrows;
    }
};
```

I am getting a runtime error:

```
Line 1034: Char 34: runtime error: applying non-zero offset 4 to null pointer (stl_vector.h)
SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_vector.h:1043:34
```

Comment: First of all figure out the input for your program that causes the crash. Then create a [mre]. Then build (with extra warnings enabled, treated as errors) the program locally on your own system. Lastly use a [*debugger*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) to catch the crash and see when and where in *your* code it happens.

Comment: And as a *possible* hint about the crash: Your `compare` function doesn't satisfy [the requirements](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare) needed by [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort). More specifically it doesn't follow the [string weak ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings) requirement. That leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Have you thought about what happens to your code if points.size() == 0? One of the basic rules of programming : never trust your input.

Comment: Also note this is a group about C++. Just so you know, leetcode generally teaches more bad practices then teach you good C++.  It should only be used to train your problem solving skills.

Comment: Please show (point out) the error line.

Answer (score 3):

```
bool compare(vector<int> &a,vector<int> &b){
          return a[1]<=b[1];
}
```

should be

```
bool compare(const vector<int> &a, const vector<int> &b){
          return a[1]<b[1];
}
```

Comparators must define a *strict weak ordering*. One consequence of that is that they must return `false` for equal values, so `<=` is incorrect.

Looking at the error message however, I suspect that the immediate cause of your problems is that the vector `points` has size zero and so `end=points[0][1]` is an out of bounds vector access.